# SonarQube 4.3 Doesn't work after adding python plugin version 1.3

Tags: python, sonarqube, metrics

- I am running **Sonar Qube version 4.3** on Linux Box.
- I added the python plugin ***sonar-python-plugin-1.3.jar*** in  /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins
  (/opt/sonar is my SONAR HOME)
- The current list of plugins with which the sonarqube server works is as below:

  - sonar-surefire-plugin-2.1.jar
  - sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.1.jar
  - sonar-java-plugin-2.1.jar
  - sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.1.jar
  - sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.1.jar

On restart after adding python jar, the sonar server does not come up.

**Error**

```
2014.07.22 02:20:46 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformServletContextListener]  Fail to start server
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/SonarPlugin
```

When I extracted the jar, it seems the jar does not have org/sonar/api/SonarPlugin directory structure. It has org/sonar/plugins/python instead. As per the release notes of this python jar, 3.7+ version of Sonar is compatible. How can I make this work?

Comment: You must have missed something during the installation of SonarQube, because Python 1.3 is compatible with SQ 4.3 and works w/o any problem. You should try to reinstall your SonarQube.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam : What should I search for in sonarqube logs that shows there is an issue with installation. This product is working absolutely fine. Could you suggest probable reasons.

Comment: Can you update your question and post the list of all the plugins that is logged at the startup of the server?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam : Thanks for taking time to answer this. I have edited the question as desired. Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: Can you please post the full server startup log somewhere and link it on your question? It will be easier to debug.